# How to use preg_replace and htaccess to modify url?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, preg-replace

I modified it according to your suggestion

```
<a class="upheader" href="leagues/' . $rs['ext'] . '/' . $rs['uniqueid'] . '" target="_blank">' . $rs['title'] . '</a>
```

now, I get /leagues/pl/xxxxxx as the new url

however, it does not find the page, displaying File not found (404 error)

This is my entire .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule leagues/pl/([0-9]+)/?$ pl?uniqueid=$1 [L]
```

In my previous example I used 'pl' instead of $rs['ext'] to make it easier to explain. Also, I don't know how to use variables in .htaccess

I would immensely appreciate if you could show me how to use preg_replace or any other relevant function so that my code would look and work something like

```
<a class="upheader" href="leagues/' . $rs['ext'] . '/' . preg_replace('/\s\s+/', $rs['uniqueid']) . '" target="_blank">' . $rs['title'] . '</a>
```

and the url display something like

/leagues/pl/xxxxxx

pl being the variable

with the help of .htaccess

Comment: Why don't you simply output `<a href="leagues/pl/'.$rs['uniqueid'].'">` and all is good when combined with that rewrite rule? Maybe add a `urlencode()` if you really have such strange ids. But what should a regex be required for here?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however the I tried the way you suggested, but for some strange reason it doesn't work.

Comment: Which is a statement that does not help at all. What does that mean? "for some strange reason it doesn't work"? Sounds as if you specifically want to keep secret what you actually want to say. What is that magical "strange reason"? And what does "does not work" _really_ mean?

Comment: It gives me File not found (404 error)

Comment: Please edit your question above (there is an `edit` button below it) and post what you actually try. _Be precise_. What _exactly_ is the link now? What _exactly_ is the rewrite rule? What _exactly_ is the request shown in the http servers log file? You have to be _precise_ with your question, otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: I tried to be more explicit!

Comment: SO what is the script that is meant to process the request? That is not getting clear from your question. Obviously it won't be `/pl` which is what your rewriting rule rewrites to. So what instead? And I still have no idea what the regular expression is meant to do here. Oh, and BTW it is impossible to use "variables" (php variables) in `.htaccess` style files. If you _really_ need that complexity, then you have to implement a router script instead of using `.htaccess` style rewriting.

Comment: add R flag to the RewriteRules and add to your question, what result have you got. Maybe you simply need to add RewriteBase.

Answer (score 0):

Using my .htaccess as an example:

```
# Rewrites
RewriteEngine           On

# every html-element that uses a src="" needs these:
RewriteCond             %{REQUEST_URI}          ^/styles/.*$
RewriteRule             ^styles\/(.*)           /sites/%{SERVER_NAME}/styles/$1         [L]

RewriteCond             %{REQUEST_URI}          ^/includes/.*$
RewriteRule             ^includes\/(.*)         /sites/%{SERVER_NAME}/includes/$1       [L]

RewriteCond             %{REQUEST_URI}          ^/images/.*$
RewriteRule             ^images\/(.*)           /sites/%{SERVER_NAME}/images/$1         [L]

# everything else will be directed to the requesthandler:
RewriteCond             %{REQUEST_URI}          !^/core/libraries/FCKeditor/.*$
RewriteCond             %{REQUEST_URI}          !/cache/.*$
RewriteCond             %{REQUEST_URI}          !/images/.*$
RewriteCond             %{REQUEST_URI}          !/styles/.*$
RewriteCond             %{REQUEST_URI}          !/includes/.*$
RewriteCond             %{REQUEST_URI}          !^/requesthandler.php
RewriteRule             (.*)                    /requesthandler.php                     [L]
```

The requesthandler.php uses the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to retrieve the requested data from either database or filesystem.